# Firebase React Native - await response before rendering view

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm new to React Native and i'm looking for the best way to render a view ONCE my firestore query returns the object. Below is the code of the view I want to return. The USER prop is being used to reference the 'firstname' and 'lastname' of the user being returned from the query. (You can see it being referenced within the View). The USER prop is currently NULL due to this incorrect async call.

If I `console.log(USER)` within the snapshot.docs.forEach() method, I can see the object I want to use, but i'm not using async properly here, evidently, and the view appears to be rendering before the query has been resolved.

Looking for the best practice to resolve this?

Thanks!

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { FIREBASE_AUTH, FIREBASE_DB } from '../firebase/config'
import { collection, doc, getDoc, where,query, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore'
const ProfileView = () => {      
  var USER = null;   
  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    var auth = FIREBASE_AUTH
    var db = FIREBASE_DB
    var user = auth.currentUser
    
    const doFetch = async () => {
      const dbRef = collection(db, 'Users');    
      const q = query(dbRef, where("uid", "==", user.uid))
      onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {   
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            USER = doc.data();
        })
    })
    };  
    doFetch()
      .then(() => {
        return (
          <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                  <Image
                      style={styles.coverPhoto}
                      source={{uri: 'https://www.bootdey.com/image/250x250/9400D3/9400D3'}}
                  />
                  <View style={styles.profileContainer}>
                      <Image
                      style={styles.profilePhoto}
                      source={{uri: 'https://www.bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png'}}
                      />
                      <Text style={styles.nameText}>{USER.firstname} {USER.lastname}</Text>
                  </View>
              </View>
    
              <View style={styles.section}>
                  <Text style={styles.statCount}>1234</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.statLabel}>Friends</Text>
              </View>
    
              <View style={styles.section}>
                  <View>
                      <ScrollView horizontal contentContainerStyle={styles.friendsScroll}>                      
                      </ScrollView>
                  </View>
              </View>
    
              <View style={styles.section}>
                  <Text style={styles.bioText}>
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et
                      ullamcorper nisi.
                  </Text>
              </View>
    
              <View style={styles.section}>
                  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handleEditPress}>
                      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Edit Profile</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>            
              </View>
          </ScrollView>
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (!isMounted) return; // unmounted, ignore.
        // TODO: Handle errors in your component
        console.error("failed to fetch data", err);
      });
      
  
    return () => {
      
    };
  }, []);
    
   }   

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  headerContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  coverPhoto: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 180,
  },
  profileContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: -70,
  },
  profilePhoto: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 75,
  },
  nameText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  bioContainer: {
    padding: 15,
  },
  bioText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign:'center',
    color:'#A9A9A9'
  },
  section: {
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width:'100%',
    marginVertical:5,
    paddingHorizontal:10,
  },
  statCount: {
    color: '#999',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  statLabel: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#999',
    marginLeft:4
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#9400D3',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  friendCard:{
    width:50,
    height:50,
    borderRadius:25,
    marginLeft:2,
  },
  friendImage:{
    width:50,
    height:50,
    borderRadius:25,
  },
  friendsScroll:{
    paddingBottom:10,

  }
};

export default ProfileView;
```

The answer, like suggested, was to initialize the useState property like so; `const [user, setUser] = useState({});`

Also, neeed to add the following code to the doFetch() method:

```
const doFetch = async () => {
      const dbRef = collection(db, 'Users');    
      const q = query(dbRef, where("uid", "==", user.uid))
      onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {   
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => { 
          if(isMounted)                    
            setUser(doc.data());            
        })
      })
    };
```

as well as calling the data through `{user.firstname} {user.lastname}`

Comment: Try with state, set your data to state, and use that state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app has to render some UI at any moment. You can't wait for the database to finish loading before rendering the component. But you can render the UI one way now, and then render it differently once you have the data available from the database. That is the key to dealing with asynchronously loaded data from Firebase (and most other cloud APIs).

So what you'll want to do is:

1. Initialize the state with an empty user document (using `useState`).
2. Render the UI for an empty user document (e.g. "Loading...").
3. Set the user document to the state when you get it from Firestore.
4. Then render the UI for the user document.

For some example of this, see:

- [useEffect cleanup function with Firebase and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65551682/useeffect-cleanup-function-with-firebase-and-react)
- [React native call function in text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67511389/react-native-call-function-in-text-element/67511632#67511632)
- [React useEffect with async/await issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74432699/209103)

Comment: Thank you, starting to make more sense now. I have done this, and the page renders with an empty (not loaded) USER prop. I can't understand how the page is meant to re-render with the updates once the query resolves though. Could you help with that? Thank you! 

**Setting** `onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {   
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {                     
            setUser(doc.data());            
        })
      })
`
**Retrieving** `<Text style={styles.nameText}>{useState(user).firstname} {useState(user).lastname}</Text>`

Comment: Oof... don't use `useState` multiple times in a component please, but just use it once - binding it to a field/variable of that component. When data loads you call the setter of the `useState` (see the examples I linked), which automatically triggers a re-render.